# Sort using indices

Tags: sorting

I already know the sorted positions, so I want to sort based on that.

Say, I have list of `{1, 3}`, I want the sorted position to be `{2, 1}`, as 2 is the second element, 3 and 1 is the first element 1.

How should I write the sort function to be most simple.

Should I write something like `Sort[{1, 3}, {2, 1}{{_}}]`  where `_` should represent the indice of that element in the original list.

Comment: `{1,3}[[{2,1}]]`?  More generally, `list[[Ordering[list]]]`

Answer (score 4):

```
{1,3}[[{2,1}]]
```

> {3, 1}

Generally,

```
list = {1, 3};
positions = {2,1};
list[[positions]]
```

> {3, 1}